# Why does class.getConstructor(parameters) not allow child objects as parameters?

Tags: java, class, constructor, classloader

Lets say I have a parent class and a child class which extends my parent and I have the following code.

```
public class SomeClass {
  private Parent myParent;

  public SomeClass(Parent myParent) {
    this.myParent = myParent;
  }
}
```

Why is this allowed

```
Class<SomeClass> clazz = SomeClass.class;
SomeClass someClass = clazz.getConstructor(Parent.class).getInstance(Child);
```

and this isnt't

```
Class<SomeClass> clazz = SomeClass.class;
SomeClass someClass = clazz.getConstructor(Child.class).getInstance(Child);
```

The second one throws an NoSuchMethodeException. Why isn't there dynamic binding in this case but when using the normal Constructor dynamic binding works just fine?
And is there a way to workaround this problem?

Edit:
I'm trying to load jar files at runtime. At this moment I have the classes I need, loaded with an `URLClassLoader` . Next I want to create a new instance of one of the loaded classes. To create the instance i call `urlClassLoader.loadClass(nameOfClass).getConstructor(parameterType).newInstance(initArguments);`
The `parameterType`would be `child.class` in this case.

Comment: "*Why isn't there dynamic binding in this case but when using the normal Constructor dynamic binding works just fine?*" - [From `Class::getConstructor`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)): "*Returns a `Constructor` object that reflects the specified public constructor of the class represented by this `Class` object. The `parameterTypes` parameter is an array of `Class` objects that identify the constructor's **formal parameter types**, in declared order..."*

Comment: @Turing85 thank you, but why can't java figure out if the child is of the parent type? and how am I supposed to work around the problem?

Comment: @ufukguenes Who says java can't? It's just not what this exact method does. This is most probably done to avoid ambiguity, which could occur if a class extends another class and implements (at least one) interface.

Comment: If you could tell us what you're trying to do, we may be able to help you better. There is no particular way to tell Java to "check if there is a constructor that accepts a supertype of this type as a parameter" when using the getConstructor(...) method. However, Java _will_ allow you to pass an instance of `Child` when invoking your `SomeClass` constructor, such as in the expression `new SomeClass(childInstance)`.

Comment: @ufukguenes please see [my last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429166/why-does-class-getconstructorparameters-not-allow-child-objects-as-parameters#comment120934694_68429166). I edited it and added some information as to the "*why*" it might be implemented as it is.

Comment: @Turing85 why would implementing an interface lead to ambiguity? there would still be only one matching constructor.

Comment: @SamHooper I added some information on my usecase

Comment: @ufukguenes [Here's an ideone example that leads to ambiguity, already in compilation](https://ideone.com/7mRuoW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getConstructorAcceptingSupertype` below finds a constructor that accepts the given parameter type or one of its supertypes.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class ConstructorTester {
    
    public ConstructorTester(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object constructor");
    }
    
    public ConstructorTester(CharSequence o) {
        System.out.println("CharSequence constructor");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Object[] arg = {null};
        getConstructorAcceptingSupertype(ConstructorTester.class, Object.class).newInstance(arg); //Object constructor
        getConstructorAcceptingSupertype(ConstructorTester.class, CharSequence.class).newInstance(arg); //CharSeq constructor
        getConstructorAcceptingSupertype(ConstructorTester.class, Integer.class).newInstance(arg); //Object constructor
        getConstructorAcceptingSupertype(ConstructorTester.class, String.class).newInstance(arg); //CharSeq constructor
        getConstructorAcceptingSupertype(ConstructorTester.class, StringBuilder.class).newInstance(arg); //CharSeq constructor
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns a one-arg {@link Constructor} from {@code clazz} that accepts the given {@code parameterType}. This
     * method guarantees that there is no other one-arg constructor in {@code clazz} that accepts a superclass or
     * superinterface of the type that the returned constructor accepts. 
     */
    private static Constructor<?> getConstructorAcceptingSupertype(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> parameterType) {
        Constructor<?> correctConstructor = null;
        for(Constructor<?> constructor : clazz.getConstructors()) {
            if( constructor.getParameterCount() == 1 &&
                constructor.getParameters()[0].getType().isAssignableFrom(parameterType)) {
                if(correctConstructor == null) {
                    correctConstructor = constructor;
                }
                else { //see if this constructor is more specific than the current correctConstructor.
                    Class<?> currentType = correctConstructor.getParameters()[0].getType();
                    Class<?> newType = constructor.getParameters()[0].getType();
                    if(currentType.isAssignableFrom(newType))
                        correctConstructor = constructor;
                }
            }
        }
        if(correctConstructor == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No one-arg constructor exists that accepts the given parameter type");
        return correctConstructor;
    }
    
}
```

Note that there is no way to avoid an ambiguous situation where an interface, say `C`, extends two other interfaces `A` and `B`, and your class has two constructors (`SomeClass(A)` and `SomeClass(B)`). In such a scenario, even an explicit constructor invocation such as `new SomeClass(instanceOfC)` would fail at compile-time. In such a scenario, My method above will return an arbitrary constructor (either `SomeClass(A)` or `SomeClass(B)`), but does not guarantee which.

Comment: This seems to be a solution which would only work if my parameterCount is always equal to 1. But of course I could have a second loop which compares more than one parameter right?

Comment: My solution assumes you only have one parameter, yes. If you need to find constructors that accept more than one parameter, there is even _more_ possibility for ambiguity. [The section in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) that deals with finding the most specific method/constructor is very involved and complex. If you don't want to worry about finding the most _specific_ constructor and only want to find _any_ constructor that accepts a supertype of all of the parameters, then that is definitely doable. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [w.l.o.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) not solvable since we can create examples that are ambiguous. Consider the following example:

```
interface Foo {}

class Bar {
  public Bar() {}

  public Bar(Bar other) {}

  public Bar(Foo other) {}
}

class Baz extends Bar implements Foo {}
```

If we now call `new Bar(new Baz())`, the program will not compile.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/7mRuoW)

Hence, [`Class.getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)` interprets the types as **formal parameters**, not actual parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)).

---

I would strongly advice to not implement a solution that, given a situation like above, "chooses" a constructor for us. Instead, I would opt to:

- either throw some `Exception`, signaling that no singular constructor can be determined, or
- return a `List<Constructor<?>>`.

For the second approach (returning a `List<...>`), we can use the following code:

```
public static List<Constructor<?>> getConstructorsFromTypeFittingActualParameters(
    Class<?> type,
    Class<?>... actualParameters) {
  final Class<?>[] actualParametersNotNull = 
      Optional.ofNullable(actualParameters).orElseGet(() -> new Class<?>[0]);
  return Arrays.stream(type.getConstructors())
      .filter(constructor -> constructor.getParameterCount() == actualParametersNotNull.length)
      .filter(constructor -> formalParameterTypesAcceptActualParameterTypes(
          constructor.getParameterTypes(),
          actualParametersNotNull))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static boolean formalParameterTypesAcceptActualParameterTypes(
    Class<?>[] formalParameterTypes,
    Class<?>[] actualParameterTypes) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(formalParameterTypes);
  Objects.requireNonNull(actualParameterTypes);
  if (formalParameterTypes.length != actualParameterTypes.length) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }

  for (int index = 0; index < formalParameterTypes.length; ++index) {
    if (!formalParameterTypes[index].isAssignableFrom(actualParameterTypes[index])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Given the above example, this implementation will return two constructors.

[<kbd>Ideone example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/uVfwQ1)